# Python CashFlow Calculator

Tags: python, numpy, math, linear-algebra, finance

I am trying to formulate an equation that can calculate the `outstanding_balance` in one go using python. It is quite simple using the iterative process. For example:

```
for month in range(1, self.amortMonths + 1):

        # Calculate intial and future interest payments

        interest = self.originalPrin * self.rate / 12

        # Calculate intial and future principal payments

        principal_pmt = self.pmt - interest

        # Outstanding balance is reduced by the principal_pmt

        self.originalPrin = self.originalPrin - principal_pmt
```

So `self.amortMonths` is basically the monthly duration at which the loan must be payed off and along with `self.rate`, they will determine the `self.pmt` variable which is the monthly amount the borrower has to pay inorder to reduce the `self.oringalPrin` value to `0` by the end of `self.amortMonths`.

Example:

Lets say I have a loan of $1000 (OutstandingPrin) with an interest rate of 10% then my interest payment for the first month is 1000 * 10% = $100. In order to find the `self.pmt` amount I used a `numpy.pmt` function which takes the outstandingPrin, rate, amortMonths as parameters to generate a monthly payment value that will reduce the OutstandingPrin to 0 by the end of the amortMonths. Lets say that `self.pmt = $120` then the `principal_pmt = 120 - 100 = $20`. So the outstandingPrin for the next month is `1000-20=$980`. Then this just becomes an iterative process.

So I actually need some help to determine an equation that can do this in one go without the need for an iterative process. Apparently, I need to use linear algebra but I don't come from a math background so I was wondering if anyone has any ideas?

EDIT:

So something like this:

`Balance_i = Balance_i-1 - (pmt - Balance_i-1 * Rate)`.

Comment: Before you answered I stumbled across a new solution which I am trying out. Basically, using numpy, I am solving a bunch of system equations. For each term there is an equation. I put it into matrix format and use numpy to solve. A X = B. But I really appreciate your solution and time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is my solution.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,0,0,0,0], [1.00583333,-1,0,0,-1], [0, 1.005833333, -1, 0, -1], [0,0,1.005833333, -1, -1],[0,0,0,1,0]])
b = np.array([162000,0,0,0,0])
x = np.linalg.solve(a, b)
balance_arr = np.delete(x, -1)
print(balance_arr)

interest_arr = balance_arr * 0.07/12
print(interest_arr)

prin_payment = np.subtract(54631.22, interest_arr)
prin_payment[-1] = 0
print(prin_payment)

np.allclose(np.dot(a,x), b)
```

The array values I manually created them based on hand calculations. The next step would be for me to figure out how to generate them automatically given the term, original balance, and interest rate.

Answer (score 4):

Below creates a Python implementation of [this Excel example](http://www.tvmcalcs.com/calculators/apps/excel_loan_amortization) with the following values set:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

prin = 200000 # principal/beginning loan balance
rate = 0.0675 # annual rate; monthly will be 6.75%/12
n = 30 # years; total periods will be 360 w/ monthly pmts
```

Next, you can use NumPy's [Financial functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.1/reference/routines.financial.html) to find the interest and principal per period.  Note that these don't depend on your running loan balance.  The nice thing is that the results below are arrays (payment schedules):

```
months = np.arange(1, n * 12 + 1) # months 1 thru 360
principal = np.ppmt(rate / 12, months, n * 12, prin)
interest = np.ipmt(rate / 12, months, n * 12, prin)
```

Computing the outstanding balance as of a certain time uses:
[image]

Which we can define below.  Careful with signs when you implement.

```
def balance(pv, r, n, p):
    dfac = (1 + r / 12) ** n
    return pv * dfac - p * (dfac - 1) / (r / 12)
```

Also, compute a "constant" PMT value.  This is the interest plus principal and is constant throughout all periods.  It's a scalar value, rather than array.

```
pmt = np.pmt(rate / 12, n * 12, prin)
```

Finally, put the above together in table form:

```
table = pd.DataFrame({'Beg Balance' : balance(prin, rate, months - 1, -pmt),
                      'Principal' : principal,
                      'Interest' : interest,
                      'End Balance' : balance(prin, rate, months, -pmt)},
                     index=months)

# Check that the loan amortizes down to 0
assert np.allclose(table['End Balance'].tail(1), 0)

print(table.round(2))
     Beg Balance  End Balance  Interest  Principal
1      200000.00    199827.80  -1125.00    -172.20
2      199827.80    199654.64  -1124.03    -173.16
3      199654.64    199480.50  -1123.06    -174.14
4      199480.50    199305.38  -1122.08    -175.12
5      199305.38    199129.28  -1121.09    -176.10
..           ...          ...       ...        ...
356      6377.95      5116.63    -35.88   -1261.32
357      5116.63      3848.22    -28.78   -1268.42
358      3848.22      2572.67    -21.65   -1275.55
359      2572.67      1289.94    -14.47   -1282.72
360      1289.94        -0.00     -7.26   -1289.94
```